# Best platform for developing asp.net website visual web express 2010 or webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

I am fluent in Classic ASP, VB Script, SQL and have always used MS Access in my small scale websites. I am not a developer by trade, but have always done my own websites to sell the products I made. I have sold my company to a much larger company that has a hack web developer company doing their site work. They have contracted with me to redo all of their web properties and I have created prototypes for them using Classic ASP. They love it, but I know it's not what it needs to be, they don't. I have been experimenting with Webmatrix, Webforms and Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. The question is what would be the best platform to invest my time in to deliver the best product to them? The site is primarily a brochure site as their products are sold through a dealer network, but there is an online purchase component for their accessories. There is also the need for a dealer portal. Any help would be appreciated, I want to deliver them the best possible product. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I appreciate you detailing your life story and congrats on selling your business, but this is a site dedicated to answering and helping people with coding questions that actually have code to show. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry Karl, my bad. I was just trying to get some useful information from folks that are way ahead of me. I sold my business because of the bad economy and ended up in bankruptcy. Please forgive me for misunderstanding the purpose of this site. I have followed this site for awhile and I guess I was just led to believe that it was about really smart coders willing to help others.

Comment: Steve I was not trying to make you feel bad, but there are a lot of people that come on here just listing off requirements and expecting people to write their software for them for free. I apologize for my harsh comment. It seems you got an answer to your question here, but I would recommend editing your question above to focus on the next part of your architecture (i.e. the portal). Good luck to you.

Comment: @Steve, if you want to ask further ASP.NET related questions that call for opinions rather than facts, references, or specific expertise, you can post them at http://forums.asp.net.

Comment: Thanks guys, I hear what you're saying, I get it now. I did take your advice Mike and moving nicely towards my objective. I can assure you that from now on any questions here will be code related. This is the most valuable resource anywhere for coders! I hope I can be a giver at some point to return all the help it has given me.

Answer (score 2):

The [ASP.NET Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) framework is closest to classic ASP. WebMatrix was designed to make it easy to develop sites using this framework. There seems little point in recommending Visual Web Developer 2010 as it has been replaced with [Visual Studio Express for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web). You can use that product to develop sites using Web Pages or Web Forms. Which of those you choose will depend on how your experimenting has gone. You can build exactly the same sites with both frameworks. They both rely on ASP.NET and you get access to the whole of the .NET framework.